# How to invert Jacobi coordinates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

I am trying to solve a pairwise interacting N particle system. let $$\vec{r_{1}}, \vec{r_{2}}....\vec{r_{N}}$$ be the position vectors of N particles in a 3 dimensional space with masses $$m_{1},m_{2},m_{3}...m_{N}$$ for each respectively. To transform this to jacobi coordinates I have used the following mass weighted jacobi coordinates. $$\vec{q_{1}}=\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{r_{2}}$$ $$\vec{q_{2}}=\vec{r_{3}}-\frac{m_{1} \vec{r_{1}}+m_{2}\vec{r_{2}}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$$ $$\vec{q_{3}}=\vec{r_{4}}-\frac{m_{1} \vec{r_{1}}+m_{2}\vec{r_{2}}+m_{3}\vec{r_{3}}}{m_{1}+m_{2}+m_{3}}$$ and so on.
The $N$th transformation is the centre mass coordinate.Now how do I invert this transformation or what is the inversion for this transfomation written everything in $\vec{r}$ as a function of $\vec{q}$

Comment: Hint: write the coordinate transformation as a matrix, then invert the matrix using ordinary methods.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in the comment, you can write your change of coordinates in terms of a matrix,
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{q_1}\\
\vec{q_2}\\
\vdots \\
\vec{q_n}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 && -1 && 0 && \dots &&0 \\
-\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2} &&-\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2} && -1 && \dots && 0 \\
\vdots && \ddots && \\
\dots
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{r_1}\\
\vec{r_2}\\
\vdots \\
\vec{r_n}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\end{equation}
or $\vec{Q} = M \vec{R}$ (you need to figure out the form of $M$ on your own). The inversion is simply $\vec{R} = M^{-1}\vec{Q}$.